# A tricky bug in my C++ code; How to fix it?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, for-loop, counter

I wrote this code below for a tiny program that gets a string (and puts it into an array) and a number and then it searches through the array to find if it has a repeated character (and counts the number of repetition), if so; the program will compare the times that a specific character repeated and if the number of repetition was equal to the number that user had given; the program will replace them with the character 'A'. For example; if we give the program "BBCC" and the number 2, it should give us the results "AAAA". The problem is that my code works for some examples and doesn't work for the example above. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char str[30];
int i, j, k, l, number, counter = 0;
char ch;

cout << "Enter a string: ";
gets (str);

cout << "\nEnter a number: ";
cin >> number;

for (i =0; str[i]; i++){
    ch = str[i];
    for (j = 0; str[j]; j++){
        if (str[j] == ch){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter == number){
        for (k = 0; str[k]; k++){
            if (str[k] == ch){
                str[k] = 'A';
            }
        }
    }
}

for (l = 0; str[l]; l++){
    cout << str[l];
}
getchar ();
return 0;
}
```

Another bug is that if we give it the string "ABC" and the number 2; the results will be "AAC"!
I know my code is a bit messy cause I'm a beginner, so please apologize and help me to fix my problem. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is ever going to help future visitors? :/

Comment: Don't ever use `gets`, instead use `std::string` and the normal input operator `>>`.

Comment: As for your problem, learn how to use a debugger, next to the compiler and the editor it should be the most common tool in your toolbox. Using a debugger you can step through the code line by line, while seeing the values of all involved variables, and that will help you see if the code behaves the way you expect it to.

Comment: you should initialise counter to 0 at the beginning of external for

Comment: You never reset your counter. Set it to 1 in the first line of outer loop, or better, declare it there (you don't need that variable elsewhere). Also, as other pointed out, avoid mixing stdio with iostream.

Comment: Or, as an alternative to a full debugger, use print debugging. Think of where the error might be happening, and place a cout statement there that displays the local variables. Look for any that don't have a value that you expect. Once you've found something wrong, keep moving up until you find the source.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset your `counter` variable in the loop.

For the `ABC` example:

1. The loop will first count `A`s. There is 1 A, so `counter = 1`.
2. Next iteration it will count `B`s. There is 1 B, so counter is increased to `counter = 2`!
3. This is the entered number, so it will replace all `B`s by `A` => `AAC`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0 ; str[ i ] ; i ++ )
{
    if( str[ i ] != 'A' ) // because replacing A with A is pointless
    {
        counter = 0 ;
        ch = str[ i ] ;

        for ( j = 0 ; str[ j ] ; j ++ )
        {
            if ( str[ j ] == ch )
            {
                    counter ++ ;
            }
        }

        if (counter == number)
        {
            for ( j = 0 ; str[ j ] ; j ++ )
            {
                if ( str[ j ] == ch )
                {
                    str[ j ] = 'A' ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put all comments on correction + some optimizations together, please tell if anything is still wrong

EDIT :

C++11 is beautiful for his simplified for ;-)

```
map< char , vector< int > > counters ;

for (i = 0 ; str[ i ] ; i ++ )
{
    counters[ str[ i ] ].push_back( i ) ;
}

for( pair< char , vector< int > > liste : counters )
{
    vector< int > vec = liste.second ;

    if( vec.size( ) == number )
        for( int elt : vec )
            str[ elt ] = 'A' ;
}
```

explanation: i go through the array, stock each index in a list of index associated to a char (what the map is for)

at the end, i just look at the size of the vectors for each char, if a size is equal to `number` i go through this list to put each element "pointed" by index to 'A'

Comment: This works well, thanks a lot! Is defining different variables in for loops (i, j and k) necessary?

Comment: not for j and k cuz their for are disjoint, i corrected it thx :D (btw a lot of optimization should be added, cuz it's still pretty nasty :-P, imagine u got 18 'a', and n isn't 18, then you will go through the whole array 18 times, this is ververy bad, you should be able to count by going through the array only one time using a std::map< char , int >